# Is there any way to add open generic formatters to ASP.Net Core 2.0 via ConfigureServices in Startup

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, asp.net-core-2.0, inputformatter

As per the title, I would like to be able to add open generic InputFormatter and OutputFormatter instances as part of ConfigureServices in Startup.cs, similarly to how it is possible to add open generic services.

What I would like would look somehitng like this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new ProtobufInputFormatter<>());
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new ProtobufOutputFormatter<>());
            options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("protobuf", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-protobuf"));
        });
```

Is this possible in any way?

Edit:

Example of currently implemented ProtobufOutputFormatter

```
    public class ProtobufInputFormatter : InputFormatter
{
    static MediaTypeHeaderValue protoMediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-protobuf");

    public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        MediaTypeHeaderValue requestContentType = null;
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out requestContentType);

        if (requestContentType == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return requestContentType.IsSubsetOf(protoMediaType);
    }

    public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            var obj = (IMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(context.ModelType);
            obj.MergeFrom(request.Body);

            return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
            return InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that using reflection is not as performant as if I were able to use the generic Protobuf deserialiser, eg something like this:

```
public class ProtobufInputFormatter<T> : InputFormatter where T : IMessage<T>, new()
{
    static MediaTypeHeaderValue protoMediaType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-protobuf");

    public override bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
        MediaTypeHeaderValue requestContentType = null;
        MediaTypeHeaderValue.TryParse(request.ContentType, out requestContentType);

        if (requestContentType == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return requestContentType.IsSubsetOf(protoMediaType);
    }

    public override Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

            var serialiser = new ProtobufSerialiser<T>();
            var obj = serialiser.Deserialise(request.Body);


            return InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
            return InputFormatterResult.FailureAsync();
        }
    }
```

The ProtobufSerialiser is a wrapper around Google.Protobuf we have (implemented to work with a Buffer Pool for performance reasons which is subverted by the need for Activator.CreateInstance as seen in the actual implemented and working non-generic example above.)

The T would come from the endpoint.

Comment: Can you show how your formatter is actually implemented? I mean I wonder how exactly you are using generic type argument.

Comment: Added an example of both working non-generic and compilable, but non-registerable to my current knowledge example implementation to illustrate what we are doing - which is very simple (adapted from https://damienbod.com/2017/06/30/using-protobuf-media-formatters-with-asp-net-core/) - and works fine, but is not ideal as also explained in edit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, it's just not designed to provide current model type as generic type argument to formatter (in case formatter is generic).

If you measured that reflection (by using non-generic version) is slowing you down, I'd suggest to use compiled expression trees instead, and cache them. For example in this case you need this:

```
var serialiser = new ProtobufSerialiser<T>();
var obj = serialiser.Deserialise(request.Body);
```

Which can be represented as expression:

```
Expression<Func<Stream, object>> body => new ProtobufSerializer<T>().Deserialize(body);
```

Assuming you `ProtobufSerializer<T>` is something like this:

```
class ProtobufSerializer<T> where T: new() {
    public T Deserialize(Stream body) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can construct expression above at runtime like this:

```
public static class SerializersCache {
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Stream, object>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<Stream, object>>();
    public static object Deserialize(Type type, Stream body) {
        var handler = _cache.GetOrAdd(type, (key) => {
            var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Stream), "body");                
            var genericSerializer = typeof(ProtobufSerializer<>).MakeGenericType(key);
            // new ProtobufSerializer<T>();
            var instance = Expression.New(genericSerializer.GetConstructor(new Type[0]));
            // new ProtobufSerializer<T>().Deserialize(body);
            var call = Expression.Call(instance, "Deserialize", new Type[0], arg);
            // body => new ProtobufSerializer<T>().Deserialize(body);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<Stream, object>>(call, arg).Compile();
        });
        return handler(body);        
    }
}
```

And your (non-generic) input formatter becomes:

```
var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
var obj = SerializersCache.Deserialize(context.ModelType, request.Body);
```

Comment: This looks great thanks and confirms what I suspected. I shall give it a go and accept this as the answer once I have implemented it!

Comment: @tker would be interesting to hear if that gave any noticable perfomance benefits or not.